# How to download zipped file with zip4j in rest API?

Tags: java, rest, zip4j

Using *zip4j* lib I can create a zip file from a folder which contain subfolders and files. But now I want to download it to the client by Rest API, so I use `ZipOutputStream` but I don't know how to get the InputStream from generated zip file.

Method to generate zip file.

```
public void generateBulkConfigFile(HttpServletResponse response, String root, String zippedFileName) {

    File rootFolder = FileUtil.createRootFolder(root);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "test.zip" + "\"");

    ZipParameters zipParameters = new ZipParameters();
    zipParameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
    zipParameters.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_STANDARD);
    zipParameters.setPassword("1234");

    //Code to process data, write files and subfolders to root folder

    try {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(rootFolder.getAbsolutePath() +  System.lineSeparator() + zippedFileName + ".zip");
        zipFile.addFolder(rootFolder, zipParameters);

        //Todo: get inputstream from zipped file and write to response outputstream for client

    } catch (ZipException e) {
        log.error("Error: ", e);
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error: ", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The above code successfully created the zip file in desired folder. I tried adding this lines of code to output to response.

```
ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(zipFile.getFile());
IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, zipOutputStream);

fileInputStream.close();
zipOutputStream.finish();
zipOutputStream.close();
```

But it end up with the `NullPointerException` in the copy method of `IOUtils` class.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at net.lingala.zip4j.io.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:89) ~[zip4j-1.3.3.jar:?]
at net.lingala.zip4j.io.ZipOutputStream.write(ZipOutputStream.java:31) ~[zip4j-1.3.3.jar:?]
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1793) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
```

Can someone help me to get through this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why would you copy the zip file in another stream if the file exists? All it will achieve is duplicating the file. Don't you just want to return an `InputStream` to your user?

Comment: @Dici It does not duplicate the file, all I need is to copy the content of the created file to the outputstream for client to download it.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry you're writing to the response output stream, misread

Comment: However, why are you wrapping the response stream into a `ZipOutputStream`? The bytes you get from the input stream are already zipped, in your stacktrace you see that the library is trying to compress (deflate) the data again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just

```
try (Outpustream os = response.getOutputStream(); 
     InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipFile.getFile())) {
    IOUtils.copy(fis, os);
}
```

You don't need to wrap the output stream in `ZipOutputStream` because the bytes you're putting in are already zipped. It's up to the client on the other side to consume these bytes and inflate them back.

Comment: Very nice, I didn't noticed it. Thank you.

Comment: No prob, by the way I also added a `try-catch with resources` in my answer because it's better than manually closing streams. It will ennsure that whatever exception occursor not, the streams or resources will be closed. Feel free to accept the answer if this fixed your issue ^^